# Grails call application.config value in javascript

Tags: javascript, grails, app-config

How can I call a value set in application config in javascript? I tried using jquery and put below in my javascript but it doesn't work. Is it even do able without jquery? Help please

```
console.log("${grailsApplication.config.getProperty('wipTransportUI.rtdService.url', String)}");
```

Comment: What file is your `console.log()` in? Files under `grails-app/assets/*` will not have any groovy expressions parsed (they are static files). In that case, you will need to include the variables in GSP's as Mike showed below.

Answer (score 0):

Your example works for me using Grails 3, I added the following to application.yml:

```
wipTransportUI:
    rtdService:
        url: 'aUrl'
```

Then used in javascript in gsp:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log( "${grailsApplication.config.getProperty( 'wipTransportUI.rtdService.url', String )}" );
</script>
```

Console:

[image]

If you're using Grails 2 you'd access the property differently:

```
console.log( "${grailsApplication.config.wipTransportUI.rtdService.url}" );
```